# How to stop UIView Animation when needed?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have this Code:

```
-(void)animationLoop{
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x, myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations: ^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height); }
                 completion:
 ^(BOOL finished) {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      animations:^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);}
                      completion:
      ^(BOOL finished) {[self animationLoop];}];
 }];
}
```

But I am trying to stop the animation when interacting with it, but `[myCircleUIView.layer removeAllAnimations];` won't do the job, any suggestions?

Comment: I believe that the best way in 2018 would be to use UIViewPropertyAnimator. Compared to this the old solutions seem like ugly hacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are stopping animation with `CALayer's` `-removeAllAnimations` completion callback is called with `finished == NO`. So change your animation code like this:

```
- (void)animationLoop {
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x, myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x + [weakSelf randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y + [weakSelf randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (!finished) return;
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                          animations:^{
                                              myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              if (!finished) return;
                                              [weakSelf animationLoop];
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

I also advise you not to pass strong references to `self` to blocks that are copied to heap if you don't really want to because of possible `retain cycle`.

Comment: Is using self in an animation block a retain cycle? I know it is a cycle if you use self in conjunction with a block whose queue is strong referenced in the same class. However, given that UIView's animation method is a class level method, then their should be no reference cycle? ( I ask because it challenges my understanding. Not because I'm trying to disprove you).

Comment: Great question, I didn't get the reason behind it either but thought everyone did so I didn't ask :v

Comment: @Freddy, `completion` block is copied to heap to be called later, so `self` retain count is increased. Without checking `finished` flag `self` will live forever (because of recursion). However including fix above breaks this problem, but `self` retain count is decreased much later as it should be (after animations are done and blocks are gone). As for me if I don't really want to save `self` living I don't pass it as a strong reference to blocks that are copied to heap. Just to be sure :)
I call it `a logical retain cycle`.

Answer (score 0):

Add  bool in your loop and set false when need to stop animation as show in code below...

```
BOOL IsAnimationContinue=true;

-(void)animationLoop{
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x, myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             animations: ^{
                              if(IsAnimationContinue)
                              {
                               myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height); 
                              }}
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                  animations:^{ 
                                 if(IsAnimationContinue)
                                {
                                 myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);
                                }}
                  completion:
  ^(BOOL finished) {[self animationLoop];}];
```

}];
}

Just set

```
IsAnimationContinue=False
```

To stop animation